# Brown leaves on shrub

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care

Anyone know what’s happening with this otherwise healthy looking shrub?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What part  of the world are you in, and how long's this plant been in the same pot? Does the plant flower?

Comment: Melbourne, Australia. It’s relatively new in the pot.

Comment: Having trouble deciding what it is- looks  most  like Oleander (Nerium) spp... but could also be one of the Euphorbias. And how long, precisely, is 'relatively new'?

Comment: It’s only a few months old. Planted in winter, now it’s summer here (but not that hot for some reason). I believe it’s a Leicadendrom.

Comment: Ah, okay, Leucadendron, one of the proteas... I don't suppose you have a varietal name.... how cold has it been this winter, especially in the last few weeks? Have you been watering during winter if necessary? And there is free drainage from the pot?