# Established Boxwood Shrubs Browned Leaves

Tags: leaves, boxwood

Some leaves on my well-established boxwood bushes (~15 years without a problem) have suddenly turned almost black:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x83l32wn2ko4932/2020-08-02%2010.51.12.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0eu7s2e5sn682t/2020-08-02%2010.51.21.jpg

This may be covered here:

[Brown leaves on shrub](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/42878/brown-leaves-on-shrub)

(except my leaves are essentially black and it happened almost overnight...maybe within 2 days at most or I would have noticed.)

It has been really hot here in North Texas, and it's possible I have watered too much in reaction.  Might anything else (e.g. pests, heat) account for this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like rust fungus. Cut off the ickys and spray the rest with mixture (google that) and if you cut it back it will grow back  free of fungus..water and fungus are friends but dont despair it spreads on the wind...happens to the best of us... careful not to use blower and spread to other plants. Not a terminal illness if you cut off the discolored parts.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll follow your advice and treat this evening.  Will check back in with results...